# GithubActions CI: how to find a file inside the windows VM?

Tags: windows, continuous-integration, github-actions, github-ci

I have a build failing because it doesn't find some particular file in some particular path. Possibly this file is just in a different SDK directory (because of having a new version), so I just want to search for it in the whole `C:` drive.

However, if I issue the following step in my GithubActions workflow:

```
- name: dir
  run: |
    c: && cd \ && dir /s TheFileNameThatILookFor.SomeExtension
```

Then the workflow **hangs**! It keeps executing forever and never finishes. ([Proof](https://github.com/nblockchain/ZXing.Net.Xamarin/runs/238468486).)

How to find specific files then?

**UPDATE**: after 5hours the CI process was aborted (probably by some timeout set by GithubActions infrastructure), and then I could see [the output](https://github.com/nblockchain/ZXing.Net.Xamarin/runs/238468486) of `dir /s`, if you can wait, just do that. If not, you could try what @Samira suggests in her/his answer, but IME it doesn't always work (e.g. if I try to search for a file with a long file name, it doesn't find it: [the log that proves this](https://github.com/nblockchain/ZXing.Net.Xamarin/runs/239188279), but in other cases [it has worked](https://github.com/nblockchain/ZXing.Net.Xamarin/runs/238872170)) and it's still kinda long, 40min! but not as long as 5hours...

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of the fact that bash, which is available for all platforms, comes together with set of handy tools in `PATH`.

Instead of `dir`, try to experiment with [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) - it still going to take some time (example below took ~40 minutes), but you'll be using a tool designed for the task.

Example:

```
- run: find /c/ -name "*.targets"
```

Comment: and what's `C:` in bash? `/c/`?

Comment: @knocte yes, it should be something like `find /c/ -name "filename.ext"`

Comment: launched new build https://github.com/nblockchain/ZXing.Net.Xamarin/runs/238732788, let's see if it hangs or not...

Comment: see my updated question, I upvote you but don't give the green tick :-/

Comment: @knocte You can't find the file because it simply isn't there, i think :) I've searched /c/ for .targets, see [here](https://github.com/wipe2238/github-actions-test/commit/905885d379d2e1ad676b4c60b839b9165a1e7a9a/checks/238648967/logs), and it couldn't find file with exact same name you looking for... There is few similiar, sure, but not yours.

Comment: OK looks you're right; now i'm curious why find fails, but not curious enough to run 40m long tests...